# php update operation not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning CRUD in php mysqli insert and delete is working but when I tried to update any record, the new value record gets inserted to new row instead of replacing old record value to new value. i have following code for having code for update, please suggest what is missing

home page

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
            if(isset($_GET['del_id']))
            {
                $del="DELETE FROM student WHERE id = '$_GET[del_id]'";
                $run=mysqli_query($con,$del);
            }   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>View</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
<?php
include 'db.php';


   $show="select * from student";
   $run=mysqli_query($con,$show);   
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
   {
        echo ' 
                <tr>
                        <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row[2].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="view.php?user_id='.$row[0].'">View</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="home.php?update_id='.$row[0].'">Update</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs "href="test.php?del_id='.$row[0].'">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>

        ';
   }

?>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

update page

```
  <?php
include 'db.php';


                if(isset($_GET['update_id']))
            {
                $up="SELECT FROM student WHERE id = '$_GET[update_id]'";
                $run=mysqli_query($con,$up);
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
                    {
                        $name=$row['txtname'];
                        $pass=$row['txtpass'];
                        $add=$row['txtadd'];
                    }
            }
            else

            {
                        $name='';
                        $pass='';
                        $add='';
            }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="process.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="txtname"  value="<?php echo $name;?>" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="txtpass" value="<?php echo $pass;?>" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="txtadd" value="<?php echo $add;?>" placeholder="Enter Address ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_form">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where's the code which __should update__ the record?

Comment: in home page there is url for update in home page  1st page  <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="home.php?update_id='.$row[0].'">Update</a></td> then at the top i have written update sql query at the top in update.php page 2nd page

Comment: There's **no** `UPDATE` query in provided code.

Comment: this is i have followed code for update  <?phpinclude 'db.php';    if(isset($_GET['update_id'])) {    $up="SELECT FROM student WHERE id = '$_GET[update_id]'";  $run=mysqli_query($con,$up);
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
                    {
                        $name=$row['txtname'];
                        $pass=$row['txtpass'];
                        $add=$row['txtadd'];
                    }
            }
            else

            {
                        $name='';
                        $pass='';
                        $add='';
            }
?>

Comment: Do you understand that this is not `UPDATE`, this is `SELECT`? If you do - then what is your question about?

Comment: i have followed this code from udemy online free training , they have written same as about , i have added just my custom column attribute values

Comment: Then this training is a piece of crap and you have to find yourself another one.

Answer (score -1):

try this when you get the row from the database..

```
$uid = '$_GET[update_id]';
$up="SELECT FROM student WHERE id = '$uid' LIMIT 1";
```

Also, your code is susceptible to sql injection. Search ways to prevent this.

Comment: It seems you aren't foo familiar with PHP syntax?

Comment: where is the mistake ??

Answer (score -1):

As stated earlier, your code doesn't have an `UPDATE`query, in the words, your 'update page' code isn't correct at all and won't update anything.

Replace it with the following:

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$id = $_GET['update_id'];

if(isset($id))
{
    $name = $POST['txtname'];
    $pass = $POST['txtpass'];
    $add = $POST['txtadd'];

    $up="UPDATE student SET 'txtname'=$name, 'txtpass'=$pass, 'add'=$add WHERE 'id'=$id";
    mysqli_query($con,$up);
}

?>
```

**NOTE:** Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524) attacks and you should improve it once your update code issue is solved.

Comment: i replace above code with this  <?phpinclude 'db.php'; if(isset($_GET['update_id'])) { $up="SELECT FROM student WHERE id = '$_GET[update_id]'"; $run=mysqli_query($con,$up); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) { $name=$row['txtname']; $pass=$row['txtpass']; $add=$row['txtadd']; } } else { $name=''; $pass=''; $add=''; } ?> part but result is same new row added does not replace old value......

Comment: Try the new updated code, I've missed a mistake you had in the WHERE part of the query.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have opted to not include SQL injection protection steps (escaping, prepared statements, etc...) to make it easy for OP to understand the solution (he's unable to differentiate between a SELECT and UPDATE statement, so...). Nonetheless, I warned him about SQL injection and linked to a reputable page so he can learn more about it, and YES his code is also vulnerable (check "home page" queries) so my statement is correct.